# Windows 7 PC periodically loses wireless connection

Tags: windows-7, vpn, wireless-networking

I have a Windows 7 PC (Home Premium) with a ASUS PCE-N15 11n Wireless LAN PCI-E Card which connects it to a Dlink router.

This PC periodically loses wireless connectivity - no internet connectivity, no DNS resolution.   It does not lose its IP address (assigned through DHCP).

The router remains up - other wireless devices seem to work fine and wired PCs remain connected to the internet.  It's just this PC.   After a few minutes (2 - 10) the connection resumes as if nothing is wrong.

The only unique thing about this PC is that I have OpenVPN installed (version 04/19/2010,9.00.00.7)  and connected to a remote location.

Anyone seen behavior like this before and how did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely you have 2.4GHz interference which is caused by some other device. Seen a lot of it in WiFi technical support work. Suggest reassigning the channel from 1 to 11 or 11 to 1 and reconfigure it to use 802.11g instead of 802.11n ('g' is more robust, and the throughput difference, unless your internet feed > 54 Mbps, is trivial), or better yet change from 2.4GHz to 5GHZ (if your router will support it - and if not, new 5GHz routers are reasonably priced).

Also look for devices like wireless headsets, cordless landline phones, wireless gaming systems, microwave ovens, baby monitors and other unlicensed devices which use 2.4GHz frequencies but are *not* using WiFi, as they don't know how to coordinate use of the frequencies.

If neither works, then consider using an [Homeplug](https://www.google.com/search?q=HomePlug) type ethernet-over-home-wiring system, or just run an Ethernet cable. If running cable through heating or air conditioning dictwork, make sure to use ['plenum' rated cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=plenum%20ethernet%20cable) which is fire-resistant.

Comment: I've fallen back to 802.11g as you suggested, and I'll try that for a couple of days.   This is frustrating because it's an intermittent problem and I can never predict when it will (or won't) occur.  So the ABSENCE of the problem won't necessarily indicate a solution, but I'll work my way through the things you suggested and try them in turn until the problem stays gone (or until I get fed up and install a wired connection across my entire house.)